# TYPO3 extension: Is the __construct() of a class only called when the record is created via the FE, not the BE?

Tags: php, typo3, backend

A rather theoretical question:

Currently i'm working on a TYPO3 extension. This extension consists of a rather complex tree structure where the creation of a specific object/record leads to the creation of specific objects/records of other classes that are then attached to the Object Storages of this "main" class. The logic behind the creation of the Object Storages and the creating and attaching of the other classes is placed in the constructor of that "main" class. In the frontend new records and the complete hierarchical structure are created flawlessly, but when i create the record of the "main" class in the BE, the other objects aren't created.

So is the __construct() of a class only called when the object is created in the frontend via an Action of its controller?

Comment: Just try it out, but as soon as a class is initiated, the `__construct` function will be called(when it exists). When you only use static functions, the constructor won't be called.

Comment: Well, i instantiate the other objects with makeInstance... This all happens in the __construct and works as long as i use the FE. But in the BE the aren't instantiated. I dont use static functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct of your domain model class is only called in an extbase construct.

That means:

- TCA (List-View of the BE) => no call of `__construct`
- Usage in an extbase controller in an BE-Module => call of `__construct`
- Usage in an extbase controller in an FE-Module => call of `__construct`

Comment: A little question: Is there a way to somehow create the hierarchical structure of objects that is normally created when the __construct is called via the FE from the TCA List-View in the BE? Maybe putting the logic that is in the __construct somewhere else?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603955/typo3-tca-execute-hook-after-object-save-in-backend

Comment: I’m not 100% sure that I understand the question but try this. ExtBase has it’s own magic methods. One of thies are `initializeObject` and has to be an public method in your class. I do not remember if this also works for persisted objects but you could try. Basically it is run after ExtBase has initialized the object and injected all properties.

Comment: @lasse `initializeObject` is an Extbase specific thing. Since Extbase isn't used in the Backend - besides Backend Modules - it will not be called automatically for the List-View, where one only defines a TCA configuration and custom functions.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Certainly all ExtBase related features are inaccessible when working with TCEFORM and TCEMAIN in the backend. I thought that he referred to when a record was created in the backend and then retrieved through the persistence layer in the frontend.